# Overriding DDEV's default db settings in TYPO3 to point to an external Database

Tags: docker, typo3, ddev

We want to use the same (staging) database for our project within our team. So we can develop on our local machines with DDEV and can share the database, so we dont have to export the database and import it on anothers team members machine. The DDEV Project is also being stored in a GIT Repo, so each teammember can pull the newest settings of the DDEV Container onto their local machine.

I can access the external Database if I modify the AdditionalConfiguration.php, but if the DDEV Container gets restarted then it overwrites the AdditionalConfiguration.php file. I haven't found a way to set the database connection within the ddev contaienr config, so when the container gets started it sets the correct Database connection (external Database) in the AdditionalConfiguration.php.

Does anyone know how to set a custom database conenction in a DDEV Container?

Thanks for the Help.

My Environment and TYPO3 Version:

- TYPO3 v10.4.20
- Windows 10 (WSL)
- Docker Desktop 3.5.2
- DDEV-Local version v1.17.7
- architecture amd64
- db drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.3:v1.17.7
- dba phpmyadmin:5
- ddev-ssh-agent drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.17.0
- docker 20.10.7
- docker-compose 1.29.2
- os linux
- router drud/ddev-router:v1.17.6
- web drud/ddev-webserver:v1.17.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to manage your settings files in ddev, and you can tell ddev not to manage your settings files.

1. Use `disable_settings_management: true` in your project config.yaml. Then you and you alone are responsible for the settings files.
2. Take over the settings file. In this case that would be AdditionalConfiguration.php. You just remove the `#ddev-generated` from it and check it in or whatever. Then ddev won't touch it.

For more detail and nuance, see the docs on this subject, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/usage/cms-settings/

I think you could also overwrite the settings in the TYPO3 setup *after* the inclusion/execution of AdditionalSettings.php

Comment: This is what I was looking for, althoug as wolffc pointed out it has some drawbacks and I know the big strenght of DDEV is that you have your own seperate environment, which btw I absolutly love for development. We use this approach for the frontend integration.

Answer (score 3):

Its  possible as randy fay said. i would avoid a shared database vor Development instances.

Say team member A creates a new extension with some db tables and spends some time entering testing data.

Then team member B runs a database schema upgrade f
On his instance he might destroy a lot of work.

And there are a lot of similar cases where lokal configuration and Database goes hand in hand.

Our team has the following process established:
Code runs from dev to prod.
And data runs from prod to dev.

So a script creates a nightly db & fileadmin  backup. Then creates a developer snapshot (by scrubbing sensitive and cache data)

This development dump is put on an SFTP server.

The latest dump is then imported nightly to pre-production
Once a week to to QA (so we have a week for the QA team to accept a change if need to create records like new pages)

And on demand for our ddev. And i think in practice we developers update the db every 1 or two months. Because most content changes are irrelevant  for us developers.

We provideed a customer ddev script which downloads the latrst dump and imports it.

Comment: This is correct. The whole idea of local development is that you affect only your own stuff as you work. So just use ddev as intended and let everybody have their own db. (There are certainly cases where an external db can be useful for other than the main db, for example large databases with read-only data.)

Comment: The solution that randy fay explained is what I was looking for. But i totally agree with you that this is not the best way to do it for developing extensions. We use this approach currently for the frontend integration, where its very usefill when you only have to add the demo content only once. I will look into your solution though. Is there a documentation or an example how import a database via ssh/ftp?